# What are the options to auto populate metadata for data received from external sources?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, metadata

We receive quite a many spatial data from various sources and export to our enterprise database (Esri). But no metadata is available in Description table. I am looking for a tool or method to get all the attributes, which can be easily populated from the files e.g. spatial extent, projection etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the ["synchronize metadata" tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Synchronize_Metadata/001200000011000000/) from the Conversion Toolbox (Metadata Toolset).  It will populate the fields you mention (extent & spatial reference, and more! : attribute list, geometry type, number of objects, ... or number of bands, cell-size & depth for raster, to mention only a few) by reading the data structure, encoding, spatial & geometric features.

When you display a detailed view of the metadata in ArcCatalog, all fields marked with a "*" are synchronized fields, which can be updated by Synchronizing the metadata with the data structure & contents.